# Why is Skyrim being compared to MW3?

Tags: discussion

They are two completely different genres targeted at completely different users. I don't understand why these two games are being compared against each other.

Comment: A better question is why is it being compared to MW3 instead of BF3?

Comment: Listen to the recent stack exchange podcast, they [discuss it a bit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-26/).

Answer (score 34):

Don't look too hard into the "battle" thing. We're not serious about it and we're not really here to decide what game is "better" measured on page views on a website on the internet.

It's just a fun little thing put there to align the users' goals (I want to maximize my chances of winning!) with the community's goals (I want to get awesome content that gets lots of views!), just like reputation is there to align the users' goals (I want to get points!) with the community's goals (I want great answers to great questions!)

Comment: This is pretty much it. The only reason they're going up against each other is that they're both hugely anticipated and releasing within 3 days of each other.

Answer (score 5):

If you go out into other gaming forum sites, many gamers have asked "which game should I get ? COD MW3, SKyrim or ???" There are also a lot of fanboys from both sides showing competitive discussions over the game, some intelligent, some just taunting.

For many people choosing a game for $60 is a big decision. There are many factors like girlfriends, wives, budgets, and parents that may prevent a person from getting both titles.

Or you just may hate or love one of the games and want to show your hatred/support!

It's like if I (hypothetically) made a game show called "Which is better : Ferraris or Ninjas?!?" It's not that you can really prove which is "better"... it's just FUN. Remember fun?
I do! It's why I play games... :)

If you visit the SkyrimVSmw3.com site it also explains that our gaming site doesn't have a lot of presence in the very popular and also very high volume console and editorial gaming channels, which is something we'd like to change.

So if this seemingly ridiculous rivalry stirs questions, controversy, and gets attention... then - I say job well done!

Also - The games are not being "compared" the games followers are being "rated" on number of views that the each of the games get on our site.

So if you're a big MW3 player/fan you should checkout out the MW3 Q&A - tell your friends...

Are you a big Skyrim person? Do the same for the skyrim tag.

At the end of the day, games are supposed to be FUN... and this is nothing more than an excuse for us to do something unique with to otherwise non-comparable titles for the sake of the growth of this site.

Comment: Should be BF3 vs MW3 tbh the big FPS of the year Skyrim is far to diffrent and not a big enough brand game to be a rival to a game like MW3 which for that past 2 in the series has shatterd record for sales and MW3 has again selling almost 2million more copys than Black ops did on launch

Comment: I'd watch Ferraris vs Ninjas :-)

Comment: @Cem22lp then why is skyrim KILLING MW3 in views here at gaming.stackexchange.com ??? ;) There is no reason you can't compare things FOR FUN. So sad I'm explaining FUN as a concept. Gaming is supposed to be FUN! Ferraris VS Ninjas!

Comment: check out skyrimVSmw3.com - Skyrim is double the views. Our competition is REAL and MW3 is LOSING!

Comment: I've seen some pointless websites in my time but that's right up there.